# searching google with HAP

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

How can I get href attribute from `<a class='l'>` ?

This is my code - it use HtmlAgilityPack to load the HTML source, but when iterating over `SelectNodes("//a[@class='l']")` in the *foreach* loop doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```
HtmlWeb siec = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldokument = siec.Load(@"https://www.google.pl/search?q=beer");
List<string> list = new List<string>();

if (htmldokument != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode text in htmldokument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='l']"))
    {

        list.Add(text.InnerHtml);
        Console.WriteLine(text.InnerHtml);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to HtmlNode attributes like that:

`node.Attributes["name"].Value`

or even better (just in case the attribute does not exist):

```
node.GetAttributeValue("name", "")
```

If the attribute `name` is not found, an empty string will be returned.

---

```
HtmlWeb siec = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldokument = siec.Load(@"https://www.google.pl/search?q=beer");
List<string> list = new List<string>();

if (htmldokument != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode text in htmldokument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='l']"))
    {
        var href = text.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
        list.Add(href);
        Console.WriteLine(href);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```